# How to prove the probability $P(Z_1 > w, |Z_2| < \theta)$ achieves its maximum when they are independent

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, solution-verification, normal-distribution

everyone. I am currently stuck on a proof and I need some help. I am trying to prove that $P(Z_3 > w, |Z_2| < \theta) > P(Z_1 > w, |Z_2| < \theta)$, where $Z_1, Z_2$, and $Z_3$ are standard normal distributions. $Z_3$ and $Z_2$ are independent, while $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are correlated. The values of $w$ and $\theta$ can be any positive number. In other words, I want to prove that the probability reaches its maximum when the correlation coefficient is equal to $0$. This proof is pretty important to me. Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Why is this problem important?

Comment: Please show at least some attempt. Even if you cannot solve it completely, there are many easy/elementary ways to approach this problem. If even that fails, then at least give a numerical computation confirming your conjecture.

Comment: @Amir I am writing a paper based on this proof

Comment: @Andrew I try to differentiate the probability with respect to correlation coefficients, but it is getting more and more complicated, and there is no closed form

Comment: Could you provide some plots of the probability for different values of $w$ and $\theta$.

Comment: You will need a further requirement, that $(Z_1,Z_2)$ is bivariate normal.   Otherwise there will be examples where $P(Z_1 > w, |Z_2| < \theta) = \min\big(P(Z_1 > w), P(|Z_2| < \theta)\big) > P(Z_3 > w, |Z_2| < \theta)$